# How to handle EF not detecting value changes when setting a nullable relationship property to null?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, nullable

I am currently facing an issue with Entity Framework (EF) where it doesn't recognize value changes when I set a nullable property to null. After investigating, I noticed that the DetectChanges method fails to detect this specific change.

Here's a code snippet illustrating the problem:

```cs
using var db = Db_factory.CreateDbContext();
var item1 = db.Items.Find(1)!; // Existing item with related Tag.
item1.Tag = null;  // From existing value to null
db.SaveChanges();
item1.Tag; // <-- Not null here! Why?!
}
```

As a workaround to address this situation and help EF detect the change, I have tried loading the related model like so:

```
db.Entry(item1).Reference(i => i.Tag).Load(); // Workaround
item1.Tag = null;
```

However, I've realized that this workaround comes with a potential downside: if I forget to load the related item, my code will fail. I'm concerned that relying on this approach might not be the best solution in the long run.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to effectively deal with this issue. How can I make sure EF detects the value change without resorting to potentially risky workarounds?

Thank you for your time and expertise!

---

#### Full test

```cs
/*
dotnet add package FluentAssertions
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
*/
namespace efsetp;

using FluentAssertions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Tag? Tag { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"Tag: {Id}";
}

public class TestDbContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; } = default!;
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        =>
        optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlite("Data Source=file:f1?mode=memory&cache=shared");
}

public class NullableRelationShipItegrationTest
{
    private const int ItemNumber1 = 1, TagId1 = 1, TagId2 = 2;
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<TestDbContext> Db_factory = 
        new ServiceCollection()
        .AddDbContextFactory<TestDbContext>()
        .BuildServiceProvider()
        .GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<TestDbContext>>();

    [Fact]
    public void ChangingRelationShipValues()
    {
        // Arrange            
        using var db = Db_factory.CreateDbContext();
        db.Database.EnsureCreated();

        var tag1 = new Tag() {Id = TagId1};
        var item1 = new Item() {Id = ItemNumber1, Tag = tag1};
        db.Items.Add(item1);

        var tag2 = new Tag() {Id = TagId2};
        db.Tags.Add(tag2);
        db.SaveChanges();

        // Act - Assert
        UoW_changetag(TagId2);
        db.Entry(item1).Reload();
        (item1.Tag?.Id).Should().Be(
            TagId2, 
            "We can change tag from 1 to 2. THIS IS OK");

        UoW_changetag(TagId1);
        db.Entry(item1).Reload();
        (item1.Tag?.Id).Should().Be(
            TagId1, 
            "We can change tag from 2 to 1. THIS IS OK");

        UoW_changetag(null);
        db.Entry(item1).Reload();
        item1.Tag.Should().BeNull(
            "We set tag to null. THIS FAILS! WHY?"
        );
    }

    private void UoW_changetag(int? tagid)
    {
        using var db = Db_factory.CreateDbContext();
        var item1 = db.Items.Find(ItemNumber1)!;
        Tag? tag = db.Tags.FirstOrDefault(tag=>tag.Id == tagid);
        // db.Entry(item1).Reference(i => i.Tag).Load(); // Workaround
        item1.Tag = tag;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, when you don't load the navigation property, it has `null` value. Setting it to `null` does not change anything. How do you expect EF to detect change in such case? Nope, you should take some of the ways you described, call them "workarounds" or not. Probably the easiest is to expose explicit FK property and work with it instead of navigation when updating. But it has drawbacks as well, so no perfect universal solution for all scenarios if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete). Search by the term sever.

Comment: Quote from docs: while EF Core represents relationships using navigations as well of foreign keys, databases have only foreign keys and no navigations. This means that it is usually not possible to sever a relationship without loading both sides into the DbContext.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov are you so kind to post your comment as answer? I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

To detect change, EF Core do a diff between a snapshot (do when the entity is loaded) and the current state of the entity.

When the navigation property isn't loaded, then the navigation property is null. In this case, set null in the navigation property don't trigger change :

```cs
var item1 = db.Items.Find(ItemNumber1);
var oldValue = item1.Tag;
//oldValue is null

item1.Tag = null;
var newValue = item1.Tag;
//newValue is null

if(oldValue != newValue) //if null is not null... never true
    Console.WriteLine("Has change");
else
    Console.WriteLine("No change");
```

When the navigation property is loaded (with `Include` or other alternative), then the navigation property take the value from the db. Then set null in the navigation property can trigger the change :

```cs
var item1 = db.Items.Include(i => i.Tag).Find(ItemNumber1);
var oldValue = item1.Tag;
//oldValue is the value in the db

item1.Tag = null;
var newValue = item1.Tag;
//newValue is null

if(oldValue != newValue) // if dbValue is not null
    Console.WriteLine("Has change");
else
    Console.WriteLine("No change");
```

---

But load the navigation property is extra useless work. A alternative is to add the foreign key property. Then you can modify directly the foreign key property to trigger the change :

```cs
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag? Tag { get; set; }
}

...

private void UoW_changetag(int? tagid)
{
    using var db = Db_factory.CreateDbContext();
    var item1 = db.Items.Find(ItemNumber1)!;
    item1.TagId = tagid;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Using foreign keys instead of navigation properties, the model is updated correctly. Unfortunately, the app pattern that has this issue, don't have explicit foreign key properties, only navigation properties (and also backing fields for each property). I really don't understand why EF is not able to detect the change, it has all the info to detect change: the new value in navigation property (null) and the previous value on `db.Entry(item1).Property<int?>("TagId").CurrentValue;`. Thanks about your answer.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain why EF Core don't detect the change.

Answer (score 0):

From Entity Framework 5 Onwards, you can use

```cs
context.Entry(entity).Reference(p => p.Tag).CurrentValue = null;
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/property-values.

Comment: I just put this solution on my test and don't fix the issue.

Comment: Also tried with `db.Entry(item1).Reference(p => p.Tag).IsModified = true;` that doesn't solve issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load entity with `Tag` navigation property.

```cs
var item1 = db.Items.Include(x => x.Tag).First(x => x.Id == 1);
item1.Tag = null;  
db.SaveChanges();
```

Or as you mentioned as "workaround"

```cs
var item1 = db.Items.Find(1)!;
db.Entry(item1).Reference(i => i.Tag).Load(); // normal behaviour
item1.Tag = null;  
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Your first approach doesn't take advantage of db context cache, perform a sql query also when model is on context. The second approach is what I said I would like to avoid.

Comment: How about [AutoInclude](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#model-configuration-for-auto-including-navigations) then?

Comment: Did you test it? I have included Autoinclude on my test and doesn't fix the issue.